# Pushing an object to an empty array returns the length of array and not the array

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var obj = {
    "entry": [
          {
            "obj1": "data1",
            "obj2": "data2",
            "obj3": "data3",
            "obj4": "data4"
          }
        ],
        "resourceType": "Bundle",
        "total": 100,
        "type": "searchset"
    }

var arr = [];

var keys = arr.push(obj);
```

This returns me a number instead of the array with objects. Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean a number?  Where are you seeing that?

Comment: because `push` returns the new length of the array.

Comment: Because that is how the `push` function is defined...

Comment: got it. thank you!